# How can I create a typedef representing a Dart record with named fields?

Tags: dart, typedef, record, named

I would like to define a typedef representing a Dart record with named fields but am not sure what the syntax would be.

The code below shows how to define the typedef `Command` representing a record with two *positional* fields:

```dart
/// A record holding:
/// * the name of an executable,
/// * the list of arguments.
typedef Command =(
  String executable,
  List<String> arguments,
);

extension Compose on Command {
  /// Joins the executable and the arguments.
  String get cmd => '${this.$1} ${this.$2.join(' ')}';
}
```

Comment: As soon as you start adding methods on records with relatively narrow property types, it starts screaming "make a durn class, OK?".

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Just add the named parameter list:

```
/// A record holding:
/// * the name of an executable,
/// * the list of arguments.
typedef Command = ({ // <== named parameter list begin
  String executable,
  List<String> arguments,
});

extension Compose on Command {
  /// Joins the executable and the arguments.
  String get cmd => '${this.executable} ${this.arguments.join(' ')}';
}
```